# Win32:- How to set an IMMDevice as default communication device only under the context of WIn32 app

Tags: windows, winapi, audio

I've a simple win32 forms app and I'm using the following
code to set an IMMDevice as default communication device for the app. But it is getting reflected through out the system. Is there a way I could just set as default communication device only under the context of current app ?

```
    public void SetDefaultAudioDevice(IMMDevice device, AudioDeviceRole role)
    {
        var config = new PolicyConfig();
        int hr;
        if (config is IPolicyConfig2 config2)
        {
            device.GetId(out string result)
            hr = config2.SetDefaultEndpoint(result, role);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your project a C# WinForm project?

Comment: Yes it is a C# WinForm project